# Windows get transparent when i'm dragging to move them!

Tags: kubuntu, kde5

I just moved to Kubuntu 17.04 and it has a strange (some may find it beautiful) behaviour when dragging a windows from one place to another, it makes them Translucent, like shown in the picture below

[image: Translucent Window]

I'm not a fan of this behaviour and I'd like to disable it, How can I do that?

I Don't see anything in Settings> Window management> Window Behaviour

Comment: Does `systemsettings -> desktop effects -> all effects -> uncheck Translucency` still work as a solution? https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=111&t=124202

Comment: @taifwa Path is a little bit different but it does work (Kde settings is a cluttered app) *Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Desktop Behavior > Desktop Effects

Search for Translucency and configure it.
Then move the slider called *moving windows*.